# Inner Join on 3 different tables

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 3 different tables I need to pull data from. What needs to happen is we pull posts from the posts table where the user who made the post is set as a public user, or if set as private, users they grant access to can view their posts.

Here are the tables:

```
user: id, username, name, password, email, private
posts: id, title, user, date, state
privateallowed: id, privateuser, alloweduser
```

and here is my code where I try to get the records:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$sqlposts = "select p.id, u.id, u.private, a.privateuser, a.alloweduser from user u 
                inner join posts p on u.id = p.user 
                    inner join privateallowed a on a.privateuser = u.id and a.alloweduser = " . $username . " 
                        where u.private='public' or (a.privateuser=p.user and a.alloweduser=" . $username . ")";
$resultpost = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlposts);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultpost);
```

Unfortunately, no records are being returned. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are any records returned with even the simplest of queries? For example `SELECT * FROM User`?

Comment: Yes, if I just do a simple select from any of the tables, it works fine. I believe the issue is with the syntax from the joins, just not sure where.

Comment: The following looks a little redundant to me `or (a.privateuser=p.user and a.alloweduser=" . $username . ")"` because you are already doing an `INNER JOIN` on `u.id = p.user` for table `posts`. Thus, if `a.privateuser = u.id` then `a.privateuser = p.user`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In php the white space between the dot and variable doesn’t matter. I’ll give this a try in the morning and let you know if this works or not.

Comment: Brien, thanks for the reply. a = privateallowed, u=user, and p=post.

Comment: String values need to be in quotes, so instead of using `a.alloweduser = " . $username . "`, try using `a.alloweduser = '" . $username . "'`.

Comment: @DarthMikeyD what I mean is you are performing an equal condition in the inner join, so the redundant part is everything after the `OR` in the `WHERE`. That’s just a side note.. just something to consider later

Comment: @pgngp agreed. If he adds the single quotes that will likely fix it.

Comment: I should have seen that. Not in front of my computer right now. Will try it in the morning and let you know.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond early. Ended up being busier then I thought I would be. I pasted in your code from below, but it didn't work. Unfortunately, I don't have alot of time right now to play with this. I'll have time this weekend that I can sit down and figure out what is going on. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find an answer, though I'm sure it isn't a perfect one. What I did was I broke the statements into separate select statements, and then embed one in the where clause, as follows:

```
 $sqlposts = "SELECT p.id, u.id, u.private 
        FROM user u 
        INNER JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user 
        WHERE u.private='public' or p.user in 
        (
            select a.privateuser 
            from privateallowed a 
            inner join posts p on p.user = a.privateuser 
            where a.alloweduser=" . $username . "
        )";
```

Me and another person who is pretty good with sql looked at this for a couple of hours, and we just couldn't get the select to return the correct results. We tried the following, but it returned each public user 3 times for some reason:

```
SELECT p.id, u.id, u.private 
        FROM user u 
        INNER JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user 
        INNER JOIN privateallowed a on a.alloweduser=24
        WHERE u.private='public' or p.user = a.privateuser
```

I appreciate everyone's help on this. If anyone has any other ideas, I appreciate them. I'm working on a web site that I am hoping will grow, and I want to make sure the page loads as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (@pgngp commented about needing single quotes around `'" . $username . "'`):

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$sqlposts = "SELECT p.id, u.id, u.private, a.privateuser, a.alloweduser 
             FROM user u 
             INNER JOIN posts p ON
                   u.id = p.user 
             INNER JOIN privateallowed a ON
                   a.privateuser = u.id AND a.alloweduser = '" . $username . "' 
             WHERE u.private='public';
        $resultpost = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlposts);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultpost)";
```

---

Also note, I've removed the following from your `WHERE` condition because it is redundant due to previous `INNER JOIN`'s. We can only infer this because you've used `INNER JOIN`, had you used `LEFT JOIN` you would need to leave the condition in as-is.

```
. . .or (a.privateuser=p.user and a.alloweduser=" . $username . ")"
```

Explanation:

- `INNER JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user`

  - So we have determined that `u.id = p.user`
- `INNER JOIN privateallowed a ON a.privateuser = u.id`

  - So we infer that `a.privateuser = p.user`
- `AND a.alloweduser = '" . $username . "'`

  - This covers the remaining condition in your `WHERE`